# How can I tell if a buffer is a comint buffer, eshell buffer or neither?

Tags: major-mode, eshell, comint, realgud

I have Emacs Lisp program that I want to work inside either a comint process buffer or an eshell buffer. The code I currently am using is:

https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/blob/master/realgud/common/track-mode.el#L141-L147

but this is a bit ugly and might be prone to breakage if either the comint or eshell changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test the current major-mode by querying the `major-mode` variable.

```el
(if (eq major-mode 'eshell-mode) ...)
(if (eq major-mode 'comint-mode) ...)
```

---

If you would like to test a mode, and all of it's child modes, try this instead:

```el
(if (derived-mode-p 'eshell-mode) ...)
(if (derived-mode-p 'comint-mode) ...)
```

Comment: This is simple and works. Why didn't I think of it? But things are a little more complicated. shell-mode has a parent mode of comint-mode. I could add a test for that as well, but it would be great to handle the general parent-mode case. (If other/better suggestions for handling derived-from-parent-modes, I'll accept this in a day.)

Comment: @rocky try this then. :)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had already did: https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr/commit/395db6d7723c67e86eb171feececb546b9a66a4b